# style on usercontrol doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Why isn't style attribute working on usercontrol?

This is my code:

```
<uc1:ucCredit runat="server" ID="ucCCard" style="display:none;" />
```

Note: I do not want to set `Visible=false`. Doing this would not render the element at all which is what I don't want because I am manipulating the style and it's display through javascript.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usercontrols don't have `style` property as far as I know. A quick fix would be to wrap your usercontrol into `<span/>` or `<div/>` and giving it appropriate id and then manipulating them in javascript.

Comment: @Jaggu, this is correct. It is much like a PlaceHolder control. It has a lot of functionality server side, but client side, the tag itself does not render any HTML. So has no client side attributes.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't working as the `<uc1:ucCredit>` tag isnt rendered.

Another idea might be to put something like this:

Markup:

```
<uc1:ucCredit runat="server" ID="ucCCard" Display="none" />
```

VB.NET:

```
Public Display as String

Sub Page_Load()
    If Not Display = Nothing then
        div.attributes("style") = string.format("display:{0};", display)
    End IF
End Sub
```

In this example `div` is a `div` which is wrapped around the content in the user control

Answer (score 0):

You can not use style attribute there, because the usercontrol not rendered as an HTML element.
I would suggest to wrap it to a div.

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <uc1:ucCredit runat="server" ID="ucCCard"  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a property in the user control which will identify if the user control is visible or not and you have to put all your controls in a panel and set it's display to none